# Premake4 utility and application entry point

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, lua, premake

I use premake4.exe utility for generate project files for different platforms.
The problem is that I could not find how to specify custom application entry point in lua-config file.

Which option should I use?
For example, in Visual Studio I can go to

```
Project Properties->Linker->Advanced
Entry Point  = name_of_my_entry_point_function
```

In premake4 manual (http://industriousone.com/flags)
 I found only **WinMain()** flag that determinate WinMain function as application entry point, but I need custom entry point for example like a **wmain()**.

Comment: Have you tried `flags{ ["WinMain"] = "wmain" }` ? Looking at the source it would seem such a construct might work, even though I haven't tried myself.

Comment: Unfortunately this way is not working ((

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no field to specify a custom entrypoint in Premake4. Indeed, I'm not sure that GCC even allows a custom entrypoint, so it would be platform-specific.

But, since you're being platform-specific, you can always just specify additional command-line arguments. For example:

```
configuration { "vc2008" }
  linkoptions { "/ENTRY:<function name here>" }
```

BTW, it should be noted that [the MSDN docs for this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9t8842e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) seem to suggest that using it will *not* properly initialize global static objects. So use this with care. For more information, see [What is the difference between main and mainCRTStartup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934206/what-is-the-difference-between-main-and-maincrtstartup)