# Printf Access Violation when called from process entry point

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, masm, masm64

I'm a beginner assembly programmer. I'm trying to create a Hello World on Windows with Visual Studio 2022. Whatever I try, I keep having the same error. I looked around on the web but my code seems fine. I must be missing something.

```
includelib libcmt.lib
includelib libvcruntime.lib
includelib libucrt.lib
includelib legacy_stdio_definitions.lib

ExitProcess proto
printf proto

.data
    fmt byte "%s",13,10,0
    hello byte "Hello world!",0

.code
main proc
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 40
    lea rcx, fmt
    lea rdx, hello
    call printf
    add rsp, 40

    mov rcx, 0
    call ExitProcess

main endp
end
```

I get an access violation at `printf`. I omit the epilog because it breaks before that.

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFF2FAD34F6 (ntdll.dll) in hello_world.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location
```

Here is the command line generated by Visual Studio for the linker:

```
/OUT:"x64\Debug\hello_world.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT
/PDB:"x64\Debug\hello_world.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "libucrt.lib"
"kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib"
"advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" 
"odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /ENTRY:"main" /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"x64\Debug\hello_world.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE 
/MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" 
/ManifestFile:"x64\Debug\hello_world.exe.intermediate.manifest" 
/LTCGOUT:"x64\Debug\hello_world.iobj" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT 
/ILK:"x64\Debug\hello_world.ilk" /NOLOGO /TLBID:1
```

Comment: How are you compiling and linking this?  If you're linking to the C runtime library, you can just `ret`.  You don't need to call `ExitProcess`.

Comment: And if you're not linking the C runtime library, then that's the problem -- printf doesn't work unless the C runtime has been initialized.  So, if you did `/entry:main` in the linker, that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks @TimRoberts, I left the Visual Studio default values. Yes, /ENTRY:"main" is there. What should I put instead ? For the C runtime, I included it in the with `includelib libucrt.lib` in the header.

I will include the visual studio generated command line in my question.

Comment: You need to use `/ENTRY:mainCRTStartup`.  That's an entry point inside the C run-time library which will initialize the library and the heap, and then call your `main`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934206/what-is-the-difference-between-main-and-maincrtstartup

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much @TimRoberts. I would not have found it by myself!